# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form with the wmd editor on it. The input text area is rendered using:

```
<%: Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.NewsBody, new{@class="wmd-panel", id="wmd-input"}) %>
```

Every time I submit the form I get `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`

I tried setting [ValidateInput(false)] on the action method, I tried adding 
    `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to the web.config and I've tried `validateRequest="false"` in the pages directive in web.config but it's still happening.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Action method:

```
 [ILFFAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")] // this is a custom auth attrobite
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult AddNews(FormCollection col){

        //public ActionResult AddNews(News news)
        //{
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                News news = new News();
                news.NewsDate = DateTime.Now;
                news.NewsPosterId = 0;

                news.NewsTitle = col["NewsTitle"];
                news.NewsBody = col["NewsBody"];
                newsRepository.Add(news);
                newsRepository.Save();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to cover all bases, the ValidateInput(false) is on the POST method, correct?

Comment: i'm sorry, i think you're not quite getting the `FormCollection` thing. MVC adds this automatically when generating an action Method for you. this FormCollection contains ALL postback material. you can easily do this: `public ActionResult AddNews(FormCollection col, News news){` although that doesnt fix your problem. and when you dont need anything besides the news, you probably can remove the `Formcollection`

Comment: When using MVC3 you can not use `FormCollection` when using `[AllowHtml]`. you then should use your `News news`

Answer (score 25):

You need to place this on top of your `[HttpPost]` action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection collection) {
       .....
    }
```

If you are using MVC3 then you should't use `[ValidateInput(false)]` but use `[AllowHtml]` which is explained here: http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/08/24/how-to-allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc/

**also:** try putting `[ValidateInput(false)]` above your `[HttpPost]` not under, As I remember, these get executed top to bottom.

Comment: i have [ValidateInput(false)] added, does it matter that I don't have FormCollection as a param though?

Comment: can you edit your post with the whole action method? try adding a FormCollection. it might just help.

Comment: try putting `[AllowHtml]` on top of your `NewsBody`. what version of MVC do you run? you need to place the `[AllowHtml]` where you define your News object, on the `NewsBody` property. did you not forget to build?

Comment: tried moving it above, didn't work. It's MVC2, sorry, should have said that

Comment: should i be adding anything to web.config with these solutions? I have both the httpRuntime and pages things in i mentioned in the original question.

Comment: neither are necessary. try removing them.

Comment: can you show the html you are inputting in the textarea? try to put a breakpoint on the calling of your action method and see where the error is called.

Comment: the Post action method isn't called at all it seems, I set a breakpoint for it but it wasn't hit.  The html im inputting is basic stuff from the wmd editor. Spans, paragraphs etc.

Comment: and when you remove the WMD editor, and input some normal text. does it work then? and when you input a simple `<p>` ? it's hard to debug this thing :)

Comment: yea if i remove the wmd and just pass a normal texarea with <p>hi</p> in it i get the same error

Comment: maybe you can upgrade to MVC 3.0. unless there is a good reason not to?

Comment: Ill try that in future, had enough for today! Thanks! :)

Comment: 3rd time i've seen this link...it's a 404

Answer (score 6):

In MVC 3, Add `[AllowHtml]` to the property in the view model that you want to not be validated.

Answer (score 4):

In the web.config file, within the  tags, insert the httpRuntime element with the attribute requestValidationMode="2.0". Also add the validateRequest="false" attribute in the pages element.

Example:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
  <pages validateRequest="false">
  </pages>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

The general rule of thumb is that you will get that error when posting to an action method that does not allow potentially dangerous form values.  If you take that into consideration along with the fact that you have obviously chosen to allow such values on a given action method, you must conclude that you are somehow posting to a different action method.

Can you try posting a standard string (i.e. "hello") without WMD and checking to see if your breakpoints in the selected action method are reached?

Answer (score 2):

use **[ValidateInput(false)]** to resolve these type of error

This happens because user input contains various html tags.So MVC3 architecture doesn't have permission for this kind of input.

> We can remove this error writing  **[ValidateInput(false)]** above a action result or where we are submitting our form. This command will disable the form validation for html tags.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution to this problem whole day.

Disabling validation was not an option.

Adding allowHtml was not an option either, because by msdn specification: 
**AllowHtmlAttribute allows a request to include HTML markup during model binding by skipping request validation for the property.** [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Also, there are a lot of properties with string attributes within a project that should be validated if the default validation is set to false.


**Solution:**

I have created a CustomRequestValidation class:

```
public class CustomRequestValidation : System.Web.Util.RequestValidator
{
    protected override bool IsValidRequestString(HttpContext context, string value, RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource, string collectionKey, out int validationFailureIndex)
    {
        validationFailureIndex = -1;
        if (requestValidationSource == RequestValidationSource.RawUrl)
            return true;

        if (requestValidationSource == RequestValidationSource.Form)
        {
            var isValid = base.IsValidRequestString(context, value, requestValidationSource, collectionKey, out validationFailureIndex);
            if (!isValid)
            {
                validationFailureIndex = -1;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return base.IsValidRequestString(context, value, requestValidationSource, collectionKey, out validationFailureIndex);
    }
}
```

what it does is that it simply skips RequestValidation for the purpose of reaching model state.

Next I have overriden the default model binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{

    protected override bool OnPropertyValidating(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                string val = value.ToString();
                int validationIndex;
                var isValid = new System.Web.Util.RequestValidator().InvokeIsValidRequestString(controllerContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context, val, RequestValidationSource.Form, null, out validationIndex);
                if (!isValid && !propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<AllowHtmlAttribute>().IsAny())
                {
                    var key = CreateSubPropertyName(bindingContext.ModelName, propertyDescriptor.Name);
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(key, ErrorConstants.SpecialCharacters);
                }
            }
        }

        return base.OnPropertyValidating(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
    }
}
```

Now here we do all the validation. In model binder I call the default .Net IsValidRequestString method along with a check if AllowHtml was set and I set the model state accordingly. It gives me control over the data and I can go back to the page and fill back the form with previously entered data without firing off inserted scripts. I am using strongly-typed models.