# MVC c# prevent xss

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I have a simple email form on my site with mvc c#.

If i added into the text box alert("test") I get the below exception:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Message="<script>alert("test"...").
```

I dont want a user to be able to insert javascript. I need for html encode i would i do this on this field

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @style = "width:800px;height:300px;" })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937127/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: look at the accepted answer at: 
[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Option 2: Put the [AllowHtml] attribute on the model item that binds to this textbox and that will let the  value into your controller where you can use HtmlEncode.

Option 3: Put the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute on your controller action, this lets everything through no matter what and then you can do your own custom validation for everything

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode to encode all user input and avoid XSS atacks.

Comment: how do i add this to the control though @Html.TextAreaFor